# How to use MEF's GetExport\ImportDefinition?

Tags: c#, mef

I've got main project, and a series of dll's that have specific implementations of some interfaces as well as view\viewmodels, etc. I use {ImportMany] to get them all with some metadata, which allows me to choose one, which gives me a reference to the specific implementation of ISystem.

I'd like to get the only specific implementation of IDisplay from whatever dll the ISystem is chosen from, which I marked with [Export("SomeDisplay", typeof(IDisplay))]
So far, the only thing that I can find that looks like it might work is GetExports(ImportDefinition), but I don't understand how to create an ImportDefinition that would work, as it seems to want a specific contractname, which isn't known until runtime.

Of course since I'm still a MEF n00b, it's a good bet I'm doing it wrong :D
So, if GetExports is the best way, how can I make it work? Or is there a better way I should be using?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look into providing metadata along with your MEF exports.

See these articles and blog posts for details:

- [Building Hello MEF – Part II – Metadata and why being Lazy is a good thing.](http://codebetter.com/blogs/glenn.block/archive/2009/12/04/building-hello-mef-part-ii-metadata-and-why-being-lazy-is-a-good-thing.aspx)
- [MEF for beginner - Part 8 - Metadata](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bnaya/archive/2010/01/20/mef-for-beginner-metadata-part-8.aspx)
- [Providing metadata to your MEF exports](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2010/03/06/providing-metadata-to-you-mef-exports.aspx)

Comment: I use metadata in my ISystem exports to provide some descriptive text so the user can choose which one to load. I'll give it a try. In what situations would I want to use GetExports?